# How to calculate the probability spectrum for a 'super roll' with all seven DnD dice?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, dice

I'm trying to calculate the probability distribution for what I'm calling a 'super roll'. A super roll is made by throwing all seven of the standard DnD dice and adding up their values.

The standard dice are:

- 1d4
- 1d6
- 1d8
- 1d10
- 1d10 × 10 [10, 20, 30... 90, 100]
- 1d12
- 1d20

I can use this equation to find $P(X_n=p)$ for a single die.
$$P(p,n,s) = \frac{1}{s^n} \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor(p-n)/s\rfloor} (-1)^k {n \choose k} {p-sk-1 \choose n-1}$$

But I don't know how to go about getting a combined distribution when I add new dice with different sides, s. I also imagine the 1d10 × 10 will cause a problem too and I imagine the above equation will need to be modified somehow.

I've tried playing around with some algebra but I'm not really getting anywhere. Can anyone help me in getting me started with this problem?

Comment: Each die is a random variable and they are all independent.

Comment: You can use generating functions or something similar to provide you with the full distribution on $\{16,17,\ldots, 160\}$.  There will not be a simple closed form

Comment: If it makes it easier, adding your 1d10 and 1d10 × 10  will give you a constant $10$ plus a 1d100

Comment: According to the way you have defined it, $1D10\times 10 + 1D10$ is uniformly distributed on the integers from $11$ to $110$ inclusive.

Answer (score 1):

You compute the convolution of all these discrete uniform laws. Convolution is explained, for example, in this wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions).